# Independent geometric variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be independent random variables with the same geometric distribution.

(a) Show that U and V are independent, where U and V are defined by U = min ( X,Y ); V = XY

(b) Find the distribution of Z = X/(X + Y ), where we define Z = 0 if X + Y = 0

Can someone explain the above question

Comment: Which version of the geometric? The number of failures until the first success, or the number of trials? From the second question it sounds as if it is number of failures.

Comment: Nothing specific was mentioned. I feel it is the number of failures

Comment: That makes the dependence even more obvious. If we know the min is $0$ then we know $XY=0$.

Answer (score 2):

> (a) Show that U and V are independent, where U and V are defined by U = min ( X,Y ); V = XY

This would be somewhat difficult to show, since $U$ and $V$ are clearly positively correlated (consider what happens to both $U$ and $V$ if $X$ is very small. To prove that they are not independent, show that $\text{Cov}(U,V)  \neq 0$.